# Need to add children to wife's itinerary

Tags: tickets, india, children

My wife booked a multi city ticket that consists of 2 round trips. She wants to now add our kids to one of the round trips. Online, we can't purchase a ticket for 2 minors only. Is there a way to purchase the tickets for the kids and link the PNR?

Answer (score 5):

Call the airline; they will likely be able to achieve this.

Comment: Airline is Air India. Hard to get a hold of anyone. It was booked through Expedia. Tried calling them and they said to call airlines.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I think you're going to have to try to get through to the airline.